# Deploy VM in Azure Stack Edge with Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-virtual-machine

I want to deploy with Terraform some Virtual machines inside Azure Stack Edge. Is it possible?

From the Azure documentation [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databox-online/azure-stack-edge-profiles-azure-resource-manager-versions), I suspect that I can use the same Terraform code to create virtual machines in a Resource Group because it seems that they use the same Azure API, but I'm not sure.
If so, how could I adapt my code to use a Azure Stack Edge instead of Azure Resource group?

```
#Creating the VM
resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "jumphost" {
  name                = var.name
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.jumphost.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.jumphost.location
  size                = "Standard_B2ms"
  admin_username      = "adminuser"
  admin_password      = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.jumphost.value
  network_interface_ids = [
    azurerm_network_interface.jumphost.id,
  ]

  os_disk {
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
    disk_size_gb         = 127
  }

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
    offer     = "WindowsServer"
    sku       = "2022-Datacenter"
    version   = "latest"
  }
}
```

This is an example how I deploy a VM.

Many Thanks

Comment: I doubt it works. For example, for Azure Stack Hub, terraform has a separate API even though many APIs are the same. Firstly, you should check `management` endpoint which needs to be supported by `azurerm` provider then only these APIs can be accessed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both The `Azure Stack Provider` and `Azure Provider` are used to manage resources via the `Azure Resource Manager API's.`.You can use the same terraform code to deploy resources in Azure Stack or AzureRM. Only you need to change the providers.

Below is screen shot from terraform registry.

[image]

[image]

Terraform, created by Microsoft partner HashiCorp, is using the same ARM REST APIs as a foundation.

For more information you can refer this [Document](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-stack-blog/azure-stack-hub-infrastructure-as-code-using-terraform/ba-p/1374530)

Comment: Thanks very much! I'll take a look and I'll try to deploy the VM using the azurestack resource. When I get it I'll post the code.
Thanks!